# Xcode enforce documentation

Tags: swift, xcode

Is there any way in Xcode to enforce documentation for each function, so that I have to write one of these for each function?

```swift
/// <#Description#>
/// - Parameters:
///   - tableView: <#tableView description#>
///   - indexPath: <#indexPath description#>
/// - Returns: <#description#>
```

I would like to get a warning whenever a function does not have documentation.

Comment: What about swiftlint?

Comment: Thank you, I missed the rule for that.

Comment: Well, actually, I still didn't find an appropriate rule. `missing_docs` only marks public stuff.

Comment: There is a configuration for that. Unfortunately, with the new rule documentation it's a bit hard to understand.

Comment: Thats what I thought, however, I don't understand how to configure it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [SwiftLint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) configuration:

```
missing_docs:
  warning: 
  - private
  - open
  - fileprivate
  - public
  - internal


opt_in_rules:
  - missing_docs
```